# Send an email based on data generated from an IF statement in column of cells?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

There are other posts about the same thing, but I can't get it to work with my variables.

I have two columns of data that use IF statements `IF(Asus!C:C=TODAY(),"Promo Today","")`.

I want to detect when a cell turns into "Promo Today" and send an email to the recipients. From my understanding, the email address had to be defined in a cell. I tried to get that into the code.

Columns 2 and 3, as I tried to target in the code, are the columns in which the IF statements are located. Do I have to target a row as well?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
Dim sEmailBodyp1 As String
Dim sEmailSubject As String
Dim sEmailTo As String
Dim Outlook As Object
Dim MasterCheck As Worksheet

sEmailTo = MasterCheck.Range("D2").Value
sEmailSubject = MasterCheck.Range("E2").Value
sEmailBodyp1 = MasterCheck.Range("F2").Value

If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Value = "Promo Today" Then
    With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
        .To = sEmailTo
        .Subject = sEmailSubject
        .Body = sEmailBodyp1
        .Send
    End With
End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: U do now uderstand what u said with , "will I have to target a row as well?" , can you be more specific ? 
Your code is right , every time column 2 changes and value is ="promo today" will send a email like you want , what is the problem ?

Comment: I think I'm reading that your issue is `Target`, that you want VBA to either loop through the Excel data and send an email for each occurrence of *Promo Today*, or send one email if *Promo Today* occurs in any cell in Column 2, both of which alleviate you having to target the cell in question.  Is that correct?  Note that `Target` is the current selection, so `Target.Row` and `Target.Column` will give the coordinates of the selected cell.

Comment: In addition to @RonanVico 's question, please elaborate more on what is *currently* happening and what is *desired* to happen via editing your post to include that information.

Comment: I would add a check to confirm your target cell is only one cell.  There are some tutorials on this if you search around.

Comment: Well the problem is that the email isn't being sent, so something must be wrong. I've tried entering a date to set the IF statement off and typing in Promo Today manually but I'm not receiving the email.

Comment: Also you have to declare what `Target` is in your first line... [see example here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)

Comment: The problem is that the code isnt running (error) ? or the code never gets into if 's ?

Comment: Well my target is B2 - B46, all of these cells have the IF statement in them. C2 - C46 also have the same statement but are instead looking for an end date rather than a start date. The dates are for future promotional events (a retail thing).

Comment: You could add a line like `MsgBox Target.Address` to have it show you if you are even getting a good value in your `Target`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Briefing

On VBA there're several ways to access a `Sheet` and the most common are through:

- The **sheet name**, which you can set on the Excel `Sheet` (and the user can change this)

[image]

And then call in your code like this:

```
Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet   
Set myWorksheet = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'The user defined Excel sheet name.
```

---

- The **Microsoft Excel Object sheet** (which you can find on the left pane)

[image]

And you can simply call it like this (assuming its name is `Sheet1`):

```
Sheet1.Activate
```

---

## Your code

So, going back to your code, since the variable `MasterCheck` is not **initialized**, we can use the first method and initialize its value:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sEmailBodyp1 As String
    Dim sEmailSubject As String
    Dim sEmailTo As String
    Dim Outlook As Object
    Dim MasterCheck As Worksheet

    Set MasterCheck = Sheets("MySheet") 'Change "MySheet" with your sheet name

    sEmailTo = MasterCheck.Range("D2").Value
    sEmailSubject = MasterCheck.Range("E2").Value
    sEmailBodyp1 = MasterCheck.Range("F2").Value

    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Value = "Promo Today" Then
        With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
            .To = sEmailTo
            .Subject = sEmailSubject
            .Body = sEmailBodyp1
            .Send
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You've mentioned MasterCheck being a variable, however that is the name of my Sheet, correct me if I'm wrong, I am an absolute beginner with VBA here, but it seems having "Set MasterCheck = Sheets(MasterCheck)" would be a bit pointless? - does this mean that my "Dim MasterCheck As Worksheet" is incorrect?

Comment: I've been messing around with things for the past hour using the edits both yourself and Christmas007 have provided and I'm still not receiving email alerts unfortunately.

Comment: @HypeHypest Don't worry I'll edit my answer to explain better why you need to initialize that variable.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I finish work in 10 minutes and won't be back in the office until Tuesday without access to my excel sheets, am I able to keep posts open?

Comment: @HypeHypest Yes, you can keep the question open, don't worry about it. Let me know if the updated answer is useful to you. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Dim sEmailBodyp1 As String
    Dim sEmailSubject As String
    Dim sEmailTo As String
    Dim Outlook As Object
    Dim MasterCheck As Worksheet

    Set MasterCheck = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName") 'Change this with your sheet name

    sEmailTo = MasterCheck.Range("D2").Value
    sEmailSubject = MasterCheck.Range("E2").Value
    sEmailBodyp1 = MasterCheck.Range("F2").Value

    If Target.Value = "Promo Today" Then
        With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
            .To = sEmailTo
            .Subject = sEmailSubject
            .Body = sEmailBodyp1
            .Send
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please revert back to your original answer, since I discovered the error before and it's against the rules of StackOverflow to plagiarize other answers. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry Louis, I saw both before the edits and after, I saw the addition that was added in the edit and if it worked I was going to credit yours.

Comment: @Louis I provided the fix related to `ByVal Target As Range` before you in both the comments and my answer.  There was multiple issues with the original code and my answer provided one of the fixes.  And the person who asked the question has already committed to your answer as well.  Because my code was not complete, it is appropriate to edit it to be correct to be a valid answer.  As an aside, I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Chrismas007 Well, you assumed that I took the `ByVal Target As Range` from your code but I didn't. I took it from my VBA (it was pretty easy to spot, if you compile the code it's the first error that comes out). But I don't want to argue and I apprecieted your upvote on my answer, so we're ok.